# Spring JPA Multiple Many-To-One Relationships in One Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to create an entity, User who has two Addresses, a home address and a work address.

Instead of storing the address info directly in the User class, I want to normalize it and store all addresses in one table and then link them to the user. Like so:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private Address homeAddress;
    private Address workAddress;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String streetNumberAndName;
    private String apartmentOrSuiteNumber;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipcode;

    // getters and setters
}
```

How do I do this using Spring JPA? I understand this is a ManyToOne relationship but I'm not sure how to map two ManyToOne relationships to one entity. Is this even possible?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem if you only want to map **unidirectionally**  from `User` to `Address`: just map both `homeAddress` and `workAddress` exactly as you would if each were the only `Address`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson so this will suffice: 

    at OneToMany
    private Address homeAddress;
    at OneToMany
    private Address workAddress;

Comment: It would be `@ManyToOne` rather than `@OneToMany`, and both would also have `@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")`.  Give it a try.  The worst that can happen is a nasty message from JPA saying "you can't do that", and then we have to try something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's really simple. Just map your **User** class like:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_home_address")
    private Address homeAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_work_address")
    private Address workAddress;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The table structure would be like this:

```
user(id, fk_home_address, fk_work_address)
```

Note that this is a **unidirectional** relationship.

The best place to look for examples if you want to learn more is [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne).
If you're looking for a **bidirectional** relation, learn [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

Now that I'm thinking more about my design, I need to account for two users who could share the same address. For instance, spouses living together at the same address or co-workers working at the same address. To account for this, I need to change my relationship from ManyToOne to ManyToMany. Is my understanding correct in this case?

Comment: No, no. The mapping would be exactly as I described in my answer. No need to change it to ManyToMany. ManyToMany is just for the case you needed this: "A single user can have multiple home addresses and multiple work addresses, and the same address can be set in multiple users". Notice that what I did was a ManyToOne, not a OneToOne. A ManyToOne means: This same address can be set in multiple users. OneToOne means: this address can be set only in one user.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
private Integer id;
private Address homeAddress;
private Address workAddress;
```

with first situation, your structure table will be

```
user(id,home_address_id,work_address_id)
```

You might consider about second structure

```
private Integer id;
private List<Address> userddress;//using one to many
```

your table structure will be

```
address(id,user_id)
```

It depend how do you want to organize the structure.

Comment: No, the structure would actually be address(id, user_id) if you put Address like a list.